# Why does the launcher not change when I tweak the theme?

Tags: unity, launcher, themes, customization

I'm trying to change the theme using Unity Tweak Tool but when I switch to one of the themes I find here: https://b00merang.weebly.com/redmond-collection.html it doesn't change anything about the actual app launcher. What's up with that?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it didn't work was because I was using Unity and not Gnome.